# Multiple compares within IF statement in Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net

In my visual basic .net app I want to do comparison like

```
If myObject IsNot Nothing And myObject.property <> 0 Then
...
EndIf
```

The problem is that I get null reference exception when myObject is nothing. So I have to nest IF statements:

```
If myObject IsNot Nothing Then
    If myObject.property <> 0 Then
    ...
    EndIf
EndIf
```

Is it possible to do this comparison without nesting IFs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use [`AndAlso`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx) (equivalent to `&&` in C#). This is the logical operator performing the short-circuiting logical conjunction. [`And`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) performs the logical operation without shortcircuit (equivalent to `&` in C#) and thus analyses both operands.

Answer (score 2):

AndAlso is a shortcircuited 'And'. If the first part isn't evaluated to true then the second part won't be evaluated and hence won't error

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this:

```
If Not IsNothing(myObject) AndAlso myObject.property <> 0 Then
    ...
EndIf
```

Maybe it work for you.